# Objective-C, properly release an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have an object defined in **header** file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *printButton;
```

In **implementation** file:

```
@synthesize printButton;

self.printButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(printWebPage:)];
[self.view addSubview:printButton];
[printButton release]; // Should I release it here?

- (void)dealloc
{
  [printButton release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

My question is, should I **always** `release/autorelease` objects (**declared as retain property**) after I `addSubview` it, and also release it in dealloc even if I'm gonna use it in other functions?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be kept around, objects need to be retained at least once.  More than once is acceptable, but the key is *at least once*.  By retaining, you're saying: 'I need this to be available', and by releasing, you're saying 'I no longer need it'.  It's rude and wasteful to retain things longer than you need them, say, after you've been deallocated.  Doing so is a leak.

To your specific question:  If your property is retained, then yes you must release at some point.  At your `dealloc` is an okay time, or after it's been retained again by something you own is an even better time.  Adding a view to your subviews is adding an object to a retained array (your `UIView` superclass retains an array of subviews).  The array itself retains it's elements.  So a release is good right after you add.

Moreover, since you know your subview array and it's contents will remain retained for your lifetime, it's even cleaner to not retain your copy at all.  This is why subview outlets are usually declared weak.  So I would do the following:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIBarButtonItem *printButton;
```

Then in init:

```
UIBarButtonItem *aPrintButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(printWebPage:)];
// this is just a stack variable, retained because of the alloc
[self.view addSubview:aPrintButton];  // this provides a second retain
self.printButton = aPrintButton;      // this does not retain because it's setter is declared weak
[aPrintButton release]; // release here subtracts one retain, leaving the one you need
```

No more explicit releases are required by your subclass, since `UIView` will take care of releasing it's subview array and `NSArray` will take care of releasing it's elements.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a `property` as `retain`, it retains the new value and send `release` message to the old value. Also you have to `release` this property in the `dealloc`.

The correct way is to do this:

```
self.printButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(printWebPage:)] autorelease];
```

Also `self.view addSubView` is retain the subView and the super view is responsible for releasing it.

Answer (score 2):

You should release your objects (if not using ARC of course) whenever you no longer need them. In your case once the view is added you do not longer need a reference to it (unless you intend to use it in your class in such case do not release it).

As @AndrewMadsen mentioned in the comment you release an object that you have an owning reference to (by explicitly retaining them or getting the reference by using `new`,`copy`,`mutableCopy`, or the `alloc` method).

You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Comment: Downvoter please explain ... its easy to down vote with no explanation. If you think the answer is incorrect you are welcome to edit it or post your own.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but the specifics of memory management are not quite as simple as your answer indicates. You should only release an object for which you have an owning reference, meaning you've either retained it in the past, or got it via a `new`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, or `init` method. Also, in the OP's example, they could actually release `printButton` immediately after assigning it to `self.printButton` since the @property takes care of maintaining a strong (retain) reference to it.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen thank you, so, I should release it even if I'm gonna use it in other functions, cause self.printButton will take care of retaining it?!

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek, yes. In particular, the `-setPrintButton:` method created when the property is synthesized will retain the value passed into it (and release the old value it retained previously, if any).